# Delete Blank Rows after AutoFilter

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have the following code in my Excel sheet:

```
Sub DeleteRows
'Filter CMReport to delete (Blank) rows.
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:G1").AutoFilter
        .Range("A1:G1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
        .Range("A1:G1").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

It will filter the blank rows but will not delete them... it says that no rows are selected. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need to do is to delete rows with blanks in column **A** , you don't need to filter, just:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: It's a good point if filter criteria is always `Criteria1:="="` !

Comment: Still not working...

I have a table columns A:G, when I filter the table it leaves rows at the bottom that only have data in Col F and Col G.

I can filter column A (like above) to find the rows, but then I can't figure out how to delete them.

Comment: I finally got it to work but I had to use this code:
`Sht.Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: @Justin_DavieHigh:  Good Job!!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this one:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False 'remove filter             
        With .Range("A:G")
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
            On Error Resume Next ' for the case when there is no visible rows
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With            
        .AutoFilterMode = False 'remove filter
    End With
End Sub
```