# Removing Row Based on Blank Cells

Tags: excel, vba

Is there an easy way to tell Excel to delete a row if a certain cell in an intersecting column is blank?  Would this require VBA?

As a reference point, I found the following VBA code:

```
Dim FoundCell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set FoundCell = Range("B:B").Find(what:="")
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
        Set FoundCell = Range("B:B").FindNext
    Loop
```

but for some reason it crashes when I try to run it.

Comment: SuperUser.com might also be a good place to ask. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions

Comment: @simoco Edited to better show where I'm coming from.

Comment: so, you need to delete row if value in column B is blank or "X"?

Comment: @Kirby That's a good point, I'll take a look there!

Comment: look into this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541846/delete-blank-rows-after-autofilter/22541933#22541933

Comment: @simoco That works perfectly, I should have checked more carefully for similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to delete all rows in which the value in column **B** is blank, then try:

```
Sub KleanB()
    Dim B As Range, rDel As Range, r As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set B = Range("B1:B" & N)
    B.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-VBA solution:

Select the column where the blanks may appear. Press F5 (GoTo), click Special and select Blanks. Click OK. Only blank cells will be select. Right click on one of the blank cells and click Delete Row.