# Excel VBA : Cannot use command on overlapping selections

Tags: excel, vba, overlapping

I try to run the following script in order to delete empty rows in an excel table. I get the error: "Cannot use command on overlapping selections "
What can be the reason ?

```
Dim Rng2 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng2 = Range("Table2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not Rng2 Is Nothing Then
     Rng2.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

Note: Change `> 0` to `> 1` if need blanks if 2 columns etc

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each Rng2 In .Range("Table2").Rows
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Rng2) > 0 Then Rng2.Delete
        Next Rng2
    End With
End Sub
```

With filtered tables you may need need to unfilter and then delete

Comment: Hi, It doesn't work. "This operation is not allowed. The operation is attempting to shift cells in a table on your worksheet"

Comment: Wow... that worked for me. Do you have other tables on the sheet?

Comment: Yes I have one more table (Table1) and the script: that I gave do work for it.

Comment: And does it overlap with table2? Though, tbh, it seems to work fine for me still.

Comment: No, they are on the same rows but not on the same columns. maybe this is the problem?

Comment: To be honest, at present I cannot duplicate your problem as works fine for me. Can we see your table layouts? Don't show any sensitive data.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help. I have added my excel layout screen shot.

Comment: Have a look at new answer. This works on any blank in row. Change > 0 to > 1 if need blanks if 2 columns etc.

Comment: Is your table filtered in some way?

Comment: Or filter table with    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" and then delete the visible cells minus header. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541846/delete-blank-rows-after-autofilter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hi, I don't know why it is, but the "Public Sub test()" solution deletes only half of the empty lines. besides that I get no errors. Thanks for your answers. I will try to figure that out.

Comment: If you do  For Each Rng2 In .Range("Table2").Rows : Debug.print Rng2.Address and look in the immediate window (Ctrl + G) - do all the table rows with blanks in appear listed?

Comment: Failing that do you have a file without sensitive info in to share?